# C error conflicting types

Tags: c

i have following error

```
error : conflicting types for 'sprintf'
error : conflicting types for 'vsprintf'
error : conflicting types for 'vprintf'
error : conflicting types for 'select'
```

in my header file, the code is

```
extern char *sprintf(char*,const char*,... )
```

actually i include `#include <stdio.h>`

but for solaries we write as

```
# ifndef HPUX
extern char *sprintf(char*,const char*,... )
```

Answer (score 5):

Rather than declaring the functions yourself you should just include `<stdio.h>`. (If you are not trying to declare the well-known `sprintf` function from the standard library, but some custom function, you should choose a different name for your function).

Your declaration leads to a type conflict since the standard library function of the same name returns `ìnt`, not `char*`.

Answer (score 3):

Don't manually declare standard functions, just include `<stdio.h>`.

(And, if you insist on declaring them yourself, at least get the type right...)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are telling the compiler to ignore standard includes (and the system C library), you probably just want to include the standard headers, i.e. as [David Gelhar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505530/c-error-conflicting-types/2505548#2505548) (the first one to answer) said.

If you are using some other C library, you would still include the standard headers, but by passing a different include path to the compiler.

You might enjoy reading up on what [`extern`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c/1433387#1433387) is intended to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Solaris man page (for Solaris DDI)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1477/sprintf-9f.html#scrolltoc), `<sys/ddi.h>` defines `sprintf` as returning `char *`. It appears that this definition of the function is intended to be used only for device driver development. If you are not implementing a device driver, stick with the standard C version instead (which returns `int`) by including `<stdio.h>` and do not declare it again anywhere in your headers or source code.

Comment: Yes, the section 9f man pages like that are for functions defined in the kernel itself, not in the user-space libraries that programs can link with.